# Trigger Jenkins job on successful Github Actions workflow

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, github-actions

I don't want the job to be triggered on `push` event but when Github Actions workflows are done and successful. In GitHub settings I see a lot of events, I think `Check runs` might be the one? But it says *created, requested or completed*, so I don't know how would Jenkins know that the workflows ran successfully

[image]